# ionicframework version update change my sidemenu - lost header

Tags: android, css, ionic-framework

I am using [ionic-animated-drawer](https://github.com/imsingh/ionic-animated-drawer) as my sidebar. It worked with Ionic, v1.0.0-rc.5. Here is [live demo](http://imsingh.github.io/ionic-animated-drawer/)

When I update my ionic from Ionic, v1.0.0-rc.5 to Ionic, v1.0.0. sidebar Header disappeared. In details, It changed structure of my layout. It add some news classes. Nothing changed but just Ionic.bundle.js to new version.

Thank advanced for all helps.

[image] [image]

```
<!-- // some html differences by each version -->

Ionic, v1.0.0-rc.5.
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable nav-title-slide-ios7 has-tabs-top bar bar-header nav-bar disable-user-behavior no-animation">
<div class="buttons left-buttons"> </div>
<h1 class="title ng-binding" ng-bind-html="title">Menu</h1>
<div class="buttons right-buttons"> </div>
</ion-nav-bar>

Ionic, v1.0.0.
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable nav-title-slide-ios7 has-tabs-top nav-bar-container" nav-bar-transition="ios">
<div class="nav-bar-block" nav-bar="cached">
<div class="nav-bar-block" nav-bar="active">
</ion-nav-bar>
```

I have to update my version for collection-repeat working properly. How can I modify my sidebar to work with version update?

Here is my sidemeun template.

```
<ion-side-menus>
  <!-- NAV bar -->
  <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive nav-title-slide-ios7 has-tabs-top">
    <ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear icon ion-android-arrow-back"></ion-nav-back-button>
    <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
      <button class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon" drawer-toggle animation="true">
      </button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>
  </ion-nav-bar>
  <!-- Center content -->
  <ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-nav-view name="mainContent" animation="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-side-menu-content>

  <!-- Left menu -->
  <drawer side="left">  
      <ion-nav-bar  class="bar-stable nav-title-slide-ios7 has-tabs-top"> 
    </ion-nav-bar>  
    <ion-view title="Menu">
      <ion-content>
        <ion-list>
          <ion-item nav-clear menu-close ui-sref="app.home" drawer-toggle animation="true">Home</ion-item>
          <ion-item nav-clear menu-close ui-sref="#" drawer-toggle animation="true">sub menu 1</ion-item>
          <ion-item nav-clear menu-close ui-sref="#" drawer-toggle animation="true">sub menu 2</ion-item>
          <ion-item nav-clear menu-close ui-sref="#" drawer-toggle animation="true">sub menu 3</ion-item>
        </ion-list>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
  </drawer>
</ion-side-menus>
```